# Curl no funciona con Amazon

Tags: php, scraping

mas bien es una consulta.
Estoy haciendo una proyecto que analiza el enlace de tienda en línea (Ebay, Amazon, etc) y trae el título, imagen y precio del producto para así hacer cálculos según el peso y otros gastos por traer al país.

Hasta ahora me funciona bien con la tiendas que agregue pero tengo un problema con Amazon, a veces trae el titulo y a veces no trae nada. Leí que Amazon no le gusta eso. Pregunto ¿El API permite hacer eso? leí un poco pero los ejemplos que muestran es por busqueda de productos o categorías, y yo necesito que el usuario solo copie en enlace y listo.

¿Qué me recomendarían en ese caso?.

Saludos.

Comment: Sería bueno que compartieras tu código de la consulta y como lees los datos que obtienes, esto permitiría a la comunidad tener el contexto claro de las herramientas que estas utilizando y darte la ayuda especifica que necesitas.

Answer (score 0):

resulta que de la url que el usuario introduzca, puedes traer algo que se llama SKU, este sku te servira para hacer un lookup en el amazon web services (AWS) y asi mismo traer todos los datos necesarios para mostrar y calcular, te recomiendo te pases por aqui [Libreria 1 (Mas facil)](https://github.com/Exeu/Amazon-ECS-PHP-Library) o por aqui [Libreria 2 (mas nueva)](https://github.com/Exeu/apai-io/)

Comment: Hola Juan, antes que nada muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de contestar. Te invito a que revises, si tienes oportunidad, la guía [_**Cómo elaboro una buena respuesta**_](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) de modo que proveas respuestas completas a preguntas bien formadas.

Comment: Voy a revisar, luego comento a ver como me fue. saludos.